# Shortcuts App Sleep Timer

Tags: books, shortcuts-app

Has anyone figured out a way using the Shortcuts app to set a sleep timer? My goal is to tap a shortcut from the Sleep menu at night, have it play audio from iBooks for 15 minutes and stop. I don’t want to have to go into the app and always  click the sleep timer.

Comment: This needs to be supported by Apple in all their audio apps! Everyone other major audio app does, but not Apple’s. I have seen Shortcuts that claim to do this, but the first one I tried was flakey and required your screen to stay unlocked otherwise the shortcut would stop. Please share if you do find a good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do so by setting my timer audio to “Stop Playing” and setting a 15 minute timer in the shortcut. Still hoping there’s a way without that method so that I can use my timers normally:

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/910f40a4029e4fbc9d359effeb1e2885

[image: Shortcuts App]
[image: Timer App]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
Instead of using a timer in the shortcut,
use Wait for X seconds (to reach 20 minutes you need to press and hold your finger on the incrementer for about 40 seconds. I read that you can create a wait for 60 seconds, and then duplicate that to your fit.)
And then use the play/pause media control. Done.